# Prove that G is subgroup of $S_\mathbb R$

Tags: group-theory

I have a question for the following proof.

Let G = {$f_n : n \epsilon \mathbb{Z}$} prove that G is a subgroup of $S_\mathbb R$

with $f_n$ defined by for each n $f_n$(x) = x + n.

If S is a symmetric group, how is G a subgroup of S? Wouldn't G contain all integers, while S would be a limited set? I understand to prove that something is a subgroup I have to show that it is not empty, closed under the same operation, and closed under inverses.

Comment: The elements of $G$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, not integers. Also, the operation is composition of functions..

Comment: Hints: $\;(1)\;$Show each $f_n$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$;$\;(2)\;$How can you express the result of the composition $(f_m \circ f_n)(x)$?;$\;(3)\;$What is the inverse of $f_n$?

Comment: I think I understand that $f_n$ is shifting each element in $\mathbb{R}$ by some number, so it's just a permutation. What does showing that its a bijection do?

Comment: By defintition, $S_\mathbb{R}$ is the set of bijections from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the symmetric group $S_\mathbb{R}$ is the set of all bijections from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

For each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, let $f_n\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_n(x) = x + n$.

Let $G = \{f_n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Outline:

- Note that $f_0$ is the identity map on $\mathbb{R}$.

  Show that $f_m \circ f_n = f_{m+n}$.

  Deduce that $G$ is closed under composition.

  What is the result of $f_n \circ f_{-n}$ and $f_{-n} \circ f_{n}$?

  Deduce that each $f_n$ is bijective.

  In addition, you get that each $f_n$ has an inverse in $G$.

  Conclude that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I can see that G is closed under function composition now, but is function composition the same operation for $S_R$?

Comment: @user406955 -- Yes, by definition, for _any_ set $X$, $S_X$ is the set of bijections from $X$ to $X$, with group operation as composition of functions.